# Heroku: RabbitMQ Bigwig connection reset every 3 minutes

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to run a background celery broker on Heroku as part of a Django webapp.

When running on Heroku with RabbitMQ Bigwig (free tier), systematically every 3 minutes I get the following connection reset:

```
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416209+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2016-11-23 12:31:04,415:    WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416224+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416225+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 280, in start
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416227+00:00 app[worker.1]:     blueprint.start(self)
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416228+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416228+00:00 app[worker.1]:     step.start(parent)
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416229+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 884, in start
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416230+00:00 app[worker.1]:     c.loop(*c.loop_args())
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416230+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 76, in asynloop
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416232+00:00 app[worker.1]:     next(loop)
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416233+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 279, in create_loop
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416234+00:00 app[worker.1]:     item()
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416235+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 42, in __call__
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416236+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.set_error_state(exc)
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416236+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 39, in __call__
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416238+00:00 app[worker.1]:     **dict(self.kwargs, **kwargs) if self.kwargs else kwargs
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416239+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 288, in drain_events
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416240+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416241+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 95, in drain_events
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416242+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416242+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 303, in drain_events
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416243+00:00 app[worker.1]:     chanmap, None, timeout=timeout,
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416244+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 366, in _wait_multiple
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416244+00:00 app[worker.1]:     channel, method_sig, args, content = read_timeout(timeout)
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416245+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 330, in read_timeout
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416245+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.method_reader.read_method()
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416246+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 189, in read_method
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416247+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise m
2016-11-23T12:31:04.416247+00:00 app[worker.1]: error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
2016-11-23T12:31:04.566069+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2016-11-23 12:31:04,565: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://my-broker    2016-11-23T12:31:04.611051+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2016-11-23 12:31:04,610: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
2016-11-23T12:31:05.714323+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2016-11-23 12:31:05,714: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
```

Something is forcibly disconnecting my broker every three minutes systematically. I'm using free dynos, so that could have an effect.

Has someone else had this problem and can help me stop this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: This also happens on my local rabbitmq server

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by disabling BROKER_HEARTBEAT.